# Can not start watch for certain application

Tags: google-fabric

I'm tiring to start watch for one of my application in order to receive the daily emails. but every time i start it from https://fabric.io/settings/apps, and leave the page,it automatically disabled. i have no idea whats happening. its just happen for my IOS application. my android application works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks David. You will need to reach out to support[at]fabric.io for this to be resolved. There is a rare state users can be in that makes it so they are unable to watch apps.

Your repro steps, describe this state exactly.

Thanks!